# How to use next js with express js?

Tags: express, next.js, web-deployment

I want to use next js but with express js as backend. Can I do that and if yes will it's static property of making dynamic website into static website will work as it is.

Answer (score 0):

YEs It is possible . Next.js is a framework that allows you to write frontend and backend code together while building the application .In the pages directory off next app
you can find an api directory which is where the backend code is written .
you can also write backend code on functions like getServerSideProps() or getStaticProps() but it wil not be displayed on the client side.

Whereas Express is a framework specifically for backend so you dont have to write some common api code from scratch by yourselves unlike in the next.js backend.

In the end whether you  should or shouldn't use express with next depends on how large and scalable you are going to build your application or not.